# Is there a way of adding different values of the same variable within the same -while- cycle?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

I apologize if the redaction of my problem is not good.

Code I'm running:

```
x=int(input("Escribe cantidad de artículos deseas comprar: "))
suma=0
seleccion=0
precio=0

while x>0:
    seleccion=(input("Dame el nombre de un artículo que deseas comprar: "))
    precio=int(input("Dame el precio de dicho artículo: "))
    z=precio
    x=x-1
    if seleccion==1:
        suma = z + z
        if seleccion > 1:
            print ("Listo. Haz anotado todos los artículos que deseas comprar")
print ("El pago total que tienes que hacer es: ", suma)
```

Result of code:

> ```
>  Escribe cantidad de artículos deseas comprar: 2
>     Dame el nombre de un artículo que deseas comprar: camisa
>     Dame el precio de dicho artículo: 12
>     Dame el nombre de un artículo que deseas comprar: short
>     Dame el precio de dicho artículo: 33
>     El pago total que tienes que hacer es:  0
> ```

*That last 0, I want it to be (12+33) 45. How can I accomplish this?

I tried writing the sum of price (precio) plus price, but it just gives me the last price times two.

Answer (score 0):

the problem, I guess, is with the indentation and illogical if-statement:

```
 if seleccion==1:
        suma = z + z
        if seleccion > 1:
            print ("Listo. Haz anotado todos los artículos que deseas comprar")
```

As per your example, `seleccion` equals 2 therefore`suma` never gets updated and remains 0

Comment: Ok, if gotten rid of the illogical statement but I still can't seem to find a way to do the sum of all the prices (precios) inputted by the user when running the code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Doubt anyone is having the same type of beginner-level issue but just incase this was the correct code in order to get the sum of the prices (precio) that were inputed once every *while* cycle.

```
x=int(input("Escribe cantidad de artículos deseas comprar: "))
suma=0
seleccion=0
precio=0

while x>0:
    seleccion=(input("Dame el nombre de un artículo que deseas comprar: "))
    precio=int(input("Dame el precio de dicho artículo: "))
    z=precio
    x=x-1
    suma = suma + precio
    x>0
    if x>1:
        print ("Listo. Haz anotado todos los artículos que deseas comprar")
print ("El pago total que tienes que hacer es: ", suma)
```